# Missing files in /media/ - help on how to write a script that will regenerate based on .htaccess call?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, cache, media, image

I performed a complete cache clean and discovered that this obliterates everything under `/media/` (as noted by me below and later correctly observed by an answer, it is indeed just the cache that is being wiped under the `/media/` folder).  Unfortunately there are some email distributions from the past that rely on these images and I am curious as to whether there is a way to regenerate all of the thumbnails / cache entries under the `/media/` folder?

So, for example, in this situation I am seeing missing files such as:

```
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:01 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/T/E/TE0213.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:01 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/X/FX0413_1.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:01 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/B/FB0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:01 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/K/FK0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:02 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/E/V/EV0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:02 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/P/FP0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:02 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/E/FEA0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:03 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/Z/FZ0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:03 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/G/B/GB0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:03 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/S/FS0413.jpg
[Mon Apr 15 11:46:04 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/265x/4df79eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/F/U/FU0413.jpg
```

When I do look for the images, for example, I do see the originals present in:
`media/catalog/product/F/U/`

The goal, therefore, is to regenerate all of these appropriately.

Moving further along in this, I can see that I need to be able to execute a Magento script upon failure of finding an image (particularly since many of these images are not being found due to being called by external references such as emails or other sites). I expect to use something like this from Apache to call this script that I'm hoping to get help on here:

> ```
> # Inside of .htaccess:
> ######################
> # if the file exists, just send it
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> RewriteRule ^cache/.*$ - [L]
>
> # if it doesn't exists, rewrite to PHP script
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^cache/.*$ /path/to/script.php?url=$0 [L]
> ```

Comment: There is no way to regenerate them - except to do it manually. afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/

It cleared the image cache.

> media/catalog/product/F/U/

Your original images are still in place, so the clear image cache function obviously did not do as you first said, `obliterates everything under /media/`

Your major problem then is that **your templates** are not doing proper media helper calls to regenerate the image. Where exactly are you having your missing image problem?

A typical helper call asks for the url, if no URL exists, the image is added to the cache on the fly with the size chosen and then the URL is returned to the html block.

`$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135)`

Product View Page image

```
<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />
```

Product Listing

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Note that the init function for the helper takes the following inputs:

```
public function init(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $attributeName, $imageFile=null)
```

and processes $imageFile with the following:

```
if ($imageFile) {
    $this->setImageFile($imageFile);
} else {
    // add for work original size
$this->_getModel()->setBaseFile($this->getProduct()->getData($this->_getModel()->getDestinationSubdir()));
}
```

POC code that feeds out resized image url when queried with image string. For Store 1 in this sample, yours according to the given URLs is Store 0.

```
<?php

/*
 * imgurl.php allows you to return image url for imgquery.
 * http://www.example.com/imgurl.php?imgurl=/l/p/lp_5009.jpg
 */

ini_set('memory_limit','256M');

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('1');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);


$product  = "0";
$imgurl   = "";

if (isset($_GET["imgquery"])) {  

    $string = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'imgquery', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    $imgquery = trim($string);

    $imgurl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $imgquery)->resize(250, 250);

}

if ($imgurl) {

    echo '<img src="' . $imgurl . '"/>';
}

?>
```

Feed it a get query:

```
http://www.example.com/imgurl.php?imgquery=/l/p/lp_5009.jpg
```

Which kicks out:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/250x250/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/p/lp_5009.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my wording above. The missing images are particularly present from old emails that included images from a week and more ago. Customers have been calling in and asking why they can no longer see images.  I have to, in some fashion, be able to regenerate these caches upon any inquiry.  As such, I am expecting that I should probably somehow create a task for cron (and manual calling) that will go through the images and regenerate the smaller versions in cache...

Comment: This is the biggest issue with email designers and Magneto - you can't link directly to the frontend image   because it's a cache that's generated with a hash. We had to learn the hard way with this. @sonassi has a great blog post on how this is constructed: http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/deconstructing-the-cache-image-path-on-magento/

Comment: As you'll notice above, I've added a little more detail of what I plan on doing to call it via .htaccess.

Comment: The helper method requires knowing the product to build its cached image, the reverse of what we're trying to do then which is to take the cached image url and have it call a function that resizes and caches the original.

Comment: @FiascoLabs would you be able to give an example script of the scenario I outlined where we have `/home/username/public_html/domain.tld/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/220x220/4da38bab36523d0886e53b8d57126395/R/A/RA01112.jpg` and need to run that via a php script from .htaccess? I simply need to see some kind of a precise example as Magento is quite new to me and I'm concerned about how this all ties together in a comprehensive script that I can call properly.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This error in my case with magento 1.7.0.2 is a bad code of zoom image module.

```
Disable it to get the work.
```

Comment: Yes the Magentothem ProZoom also giving me issues

Answer (score 0):

The files are generated, when needed. You need a call to `Mage::helper('catalog/image)->...` to create these images. You can do it either manually or you might write a script to redirect all requests to `/media/` to this script do generate the images just in time

Comment: Thanks for that!  Can you post a sample php script that I could insert into the home folder to initiate a regen of all images? I discovered a problem with permissions and have set the owner to also be part of the `nobody` group that apache has started using for some unknown reason and so that has been similarly causing problems.  Ultimately I need to evoke some method to force a regeneration of all missing cache assets.

Comment: As you may note above, I've added some more detail of the missing files so essentially I need to regen all files under the common folder structure.